# how to organize & implement jsp file structure using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm a php programmer now doing a Java web project using Spring framework. I'm trying to organize my JSP files the way i would have organized my .tpl files in php.

So if it would have been php i would have done it like this:

- index.tpl

  - includes one of layout.tpls (ajax.tpl, mobile.tpl, general.tpl, simplified.tpl . . .)

    - includes the header of the page
    - includes menus
    - includes the actual content of the page
    - includes the page footer

then from the php controller i would be able to do something like this:

```
setLayout('general');
showTopMenu(false);
setContent('mySexyPage');
```

beside that i would have organized my stuff so that my views (tpl files) will be organized in folderы each corresponding to a single controller. like this:

- userManager

  - addUSer.tpl
  - editUser.tpl
  - editUserPermissions.tpl
- articleManager

  - addArticle.tpl
  - editArticle.tpl

and in each controller somehow define from which folder to load my content template.

Now in Spring i have a controller with methods handling requests and each of the methods returning what the view should be. I can extend all my controllers from a single abstract class where i will create an instance of ModelAndView with all default values set, then request handling methods will add what they need to the instance their daddy already created and return it.

The problem with the above approach is that i'm not forcing the coder who's writing controllers to use the ModelAndView object i created, he way still return anything he wants from the handling method he wrote.

Is there some interface containing a method like ModelAndView getModelAndView() my daddy controller will implement so Spring will ignore whatever handler methods are returning?

Or is there some better way to do this ?

Comment: Spring is there to make life *more* flexible for the developer, not less. You're going to struggle to push people down a fixed route.

Comment: It's not a fixed road. In a way you may call it an design pattern. If a development team has agreed that they are going to use some approach in their application it's not usually a bad thing IMO. And locking the team to an agreed approach is even a better thing cause you know nobody will be doing it in his unique way.

What i want to do here is to have my templates organized and easy to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Content Template Issue

The Java world has a (more than one actually, but I'm sticking with the one I know) solution for this problem, it is called ***Tiles***.  check out section 16 of the [Spring 3.0.5 Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/).

### ModelAndView Issue

This is more interesting.  First, you can use Model with out view and have your controllers just return the view name (*i.e.* return a `String`).  I believe you want to create the initial Model somewhere.  Then have each controller hander method accept an argument of type Model.
Here is what I tend to do (no claim that it is a *best practice*):

Have a Controller.get(Model model) method that sets the initial values.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(Model model)
{ ... set default stuff ... }
```

Every Handler method is a variation of this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String search(Model model, ... other stuff as needed ...)
{ ... set stuff in model ... }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply :) i've been struggling with the issue quite a long time already :) I'm now reading what tiles are but the second solution with 2 handle methods didn't work for me. The method with just request type mapping doesn't get called at all, just the one with the url mapping is executed. do you know what can be the cause of this? :(

btw happy New Year! :)

Comment: Spring MVC will only map URLs to a method that is annotated with @RequestMapping, unless you map the url using xml configuration.

Comment: That is not 100pct correct, you can also derive a controller from the MultiActionController to take advantage of the "convention instead of configuration" pattern.  Also, there are likely other ways that I have not encountered.